# Heroku: Spring boot app successfully deploying; but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I would like to deploy my Spring boot app on Heroku.
When i try the manual deploy, there is no error on my log. But when i try to load the site i have this error:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application 
owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

Please find below my logs. 
Someone have an idea ?
did i miss some thing?
Any help would be welcome!

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Executing Maven
   $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
   /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] ---------------< lu.amundi:ServeurAmundiFileIntegration >---------------
   [INFO] Building ServeurAmundiFileIntegration 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:list (default-cli) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] Copying 1 resource
   [INFO] Copying 0 resource
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
   [INFO] Compiling 64 source files to /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/target/classes
   [INFO] /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/src/main/java/lu/amundi/be/security/SecurityConfig.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   [INFO] /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/src/main/java/lu/amundi/be/security/SecurityConfig.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/src/test/resources
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
   [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/target/test-classes
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Tests are skipped.
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/target/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ServeurAmundiFileIntegration ---
   [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/target/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/lu/amundi/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_3329cfca5f2723d7e41de818bf56c89f/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/lu/amundi/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServeurAmundiFileIntegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 7.676 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-07T14:07:09Z
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> web
  -----> Compressing...
   Done: 78.8M
  -----> Launching...
   Released v6
   https://amundi-file-integration-server.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `heroku logs --tail -a (your app name)` to get access to the logs, that should have some information on why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try web:node server.js Not space web: node server.js in ProcFile